# CSIM will not run in Scilab v6.0.0 or 6.0.1

Tags: scilab

in Scilab v5.5.2 this code executes without issue.
In Scilab v6.0.0 or higher I get the following error,

lsode--  at t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps
necessary before reaching tout
      where i1 is :        500
      where r1 is :   0.1202764106130D-05
Excessive work done on this call (perhaps wrong jacobian type).
at line   159 of function csim ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.1\modules\cacsd\macros\csim.sci line 170 )
at line    39 of executed file C:\Users\wensrl\Documents\SciLab\Control\optTest2.sce

ode: lsode exit with state -1.

Here is the code,

```
clear
clc

t = linspace(1, 520, 5200)

for i = 1:5200
    if (i > 15) then
        if (i < (5200 / 2)) then
            u(i) = 1;
        else
            u(i) = 0;           
        end
    else
        u(i) = 0;
    end
end

P  = syslin('c', 0.72, 1 + 11 * %s);
n = 4 // order of the delay function
delay = 1 / (( 1 + ((%s * 3) / n)) ^n); // make into a function
Pd = P * delay;

x0=[7.1373457   6.6467066   1.0393701   0.125];

kc    = x0(1);
ki    = x0(2);
kd    = x0(3);
alpha = x0(4);

// stdDeltaV PID formula
pidFormula = kc * (1 + (1/(ki * %s)) + ...
             ((kd * %s)/(alpha * kd * %s + 1)));

C = syslin('c', pidFormula);

oL = Pd * C;
cL = oL /. 1;

[y] = csim(u', t, cL)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works similarily with scilab-5.5.2and scilab-6.0.1.
But note that ode solvers are supposed to get continuous systems. Here your input is discontinuous, so the solver has difficulties to integrate it and the result may be wrong.
In fact you should make 3 successives integrations for each continuous part

```
[y1,x1]=csim(u(1:15)',t(1:15),cL);
[y2,x2]=csim(u(15:2599)',t(15:2599)-t(15),cL,x1(:,$));
[y3,x3]=csim(u(2599:$)',t(2599:$)-t(2599),cL,x2(:,$));
clf(),plot([t(1:15) t(15:2599) t(2599:$)],[y1 y2 y3])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Your method of splitting the system up worked in 6.0.1  It is still a puzzle why the script works in 5.5.2 and not 6.0.1 on my system, yet it works in both on your.